# How to redirect in a servlet filter?

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, servlet-filters

I'm trying to find a method to redirect my request from a filter to the login page but I don't know how to redirect from servlet. I've searched but what I find is `sendRedirect()` method. I can't find this method on my response object in the filter. What's the cause? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

In Filter the response is of `ServletResponse` rather than `HttpServletResponse`. Hence do the cast to `HttpServletResponse`.

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
```

If using a context path:

```
httpResponse.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
```

Also don't forget to call `return;` at the end.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve the jsp path using a viewResolver inside of a filter?

Comment: it's only work if request is come from Browser. It's outer redirect.

Comment: if is use sendredirec the conversationContext param is lost, how can i redirect with conversationContext param?

Answer (score 13):

> I'm trying to find a method to redirect my request from filter to login page

***Don't***

You just invoke

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

from filter and the normal flow will go ahead.

> I don't know how to redirect from servlet

You can use

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

to redirect from servlet

Comment: It's however useful if you want to abort the request because the user is not logged in.

Comment: `response` is of type `ServletResponse` and it should be casted to `HttpServletResponse`.

Example :
`HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;`
`resp.sendRedirect("templateName || pathName");`

Comment: Why did you tell him not to redirect to authentication page from the filter?  Please elaborate?

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: There are two issues not addressed: 1./ break the chaining of filters and servlets further down; 2./ abort further processing of filters chained prior to this one (nothing guarantees this to be the first one). Note that there is coding possible before and after the `chain.doFilter`.

Answer (score 10):

If you also want to keep hash and get parameter, you can do something like this (fill redirectMap at filter init):

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();

String[] uriParts = uri.split("[#?]");
String path = uriParts[0];
String rest = uri.substring(uriParts[0].length());

if(redirectMap.containsKey(path)) {
    response.sendRedirect(redirectMap.get(path) + rest);
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, browser won't send anything after '#' in the URI to backend. So, how is it supposed to work?

Comment: You're right. But I do remember I got an error because of the hash in the server. Maybe because I used curl or some rest client. It's cheap to have it anyway to be 100% sure

Answer (score 3):

why are you using response object . it is a ServletResponse Object ,it does not provide sendRedirect() method . instead **use request object of ServletRequest to forward the request**.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here

        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").forward(request,response);
        return;
        
    }
```

see  [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try and check of your `ServletResponse response` is an `instanceof HttpServletResponse` like so:

```
if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
    response.sendRedirect(....);
}
```

Comment: no need as filter method is `public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
   throws IOException, ServletException {`

Comment: @ToKra That is not the method signature, and results in a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

Your response object is declared as a `ServletResponse`. To use the `sendRedirect()` method, you have to cast it to `HttpServletResponse`. This is an extended interface that adds methods related to the HTTP protocol.

Comment: filters method already has that `public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
   throws IOException, ServletException {`