# Should I use servlet or filter for redirect a URL?

Tags: jakarta-ee, redirect, filter

I have read some questions on stackoverflow like [Servlet vs Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957165/servlet-vs-filter) , [How to redirect in filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308801/how-to-redirect-in-filter) ,

Basically what all I need is just a httpResponse.sendRedirect(), which can either be put in a servlet or in a filter.

If I just want to redirect some URLs based on a certain pattern to some other URLs, should I use servlet or filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I just want to redirect some URLs based on a certain pattern to some other URLs, should I use servlet or filter?

I would use a Filter in your case. Filters are primarily intented for modifying/blocking requests and/or response.