# How can I map multiple URL-s to the same view in Vaadin 7?

Tags: java, url, vaadin, vaadin7

I know how to create a multi-view Vaadin7 application with Navigator:

Let's assume that the URL of my MainView is

```
https://ga.acriss.com:8843/arranger
```

I can navigate from MainView to Dashboard view like this:

```
this.navigator = new Navigator();
navigator.addView("dashboard", new Dashboardview());
navigator.navigateTo("dashboard");
```

and in this case the URL will be amanded like this:

```
https://ga.acriss.com:8843/arranger/#!dashboard
```

If I type the extended URL to the address bar directly my Dashboard view will appear.

However some of our clients bookmarked the earlier version of our application, and their bookmarked links are something like this:

```
https://ga.acriss.com:8843/arranger/arbitrarystring/otherarbitrarystring/dashboard
```

I want anybody who enters their already bookmarked URL with the arbitrarystring extension to be taken to my one and only Dashboard view. URL-s  containing "dashboard" with and without arbitrarystring should point to the same dashboard view.

How can I map multiple URL-s to the same view in Vaadin 7?

Answer (score 1):

Use a servlet filter which redirects the old url to the new one.

[How to redirect in filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308801/how-to-redirect-in-filter)