# How to change landing page for particular group in aem?

Tags: aem

How to change landing page for particular group.

For example, I have a group DAM users, I want only this group to redirect to particular landing page and not all the groups, which have standard landing page as mentioned in ROOT MAPPING.

Comment: You are delivering the the page from the dispatcher/CDN?

Comment: root mapping is a global config, if you want to do some dirty works... you can build [HttpServletFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5308980/4648586) to check the current logged in user and redirect them to the designated landing page.

Comment: So what i meant was to change the landing page from default to a new landing page just for one group which we have created newly via useradmin.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write custom code to achieve this.
If you are using/extending [AuthenticationHandler](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/authentication/authentication-authenticationhandler.html) then you could look at implementing [AuthenticationFeedbackHandler](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling10/org/apache/sling/auth/core/spi/AuthenticationFeedbackHandler.html) where you could provide custom implementation on the redirects. For reference also look at [DefaultAuthenticationFeedbackHandler](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling10/org/apache/sling/auth/core/spi/DefaultAuthenticationFeedbackHandler.html)

You could have a service/configuration that provides group based redirect mapping and/or default redirect, for success use UserManager API to get logged-in User's instance and from that you can get group information. Use that to handle redirect on success.

```
final Session adminSession = adminResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
final UserManager userManager = adminResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
final User user = (User) userManager.getAuthorizable(adminSession.getUserID());

Iterator<Group> itr=user.memberOf();
       while(itr.hasNext())
       {
          Group group=(Group)itr.next();
           logger.info("group.getID().."+group.getID());
           logger.info("group.getPrincipal().getName().."+group.getPrincipal().getName());
        }
```

---------------------- Update Sample code----------------

There is a sample implementation in Adobe's ACS Common project and can be found [here](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/authentication/impl/SampleLoginHookAuthenticationHandler.java)

Look at method - `public boolean authenticationSucceeded(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo)`

You could provide your implementation here instead of using `DeferredRedirectHttpServletResponse`. In you implementation you need to retrieve your URL/Path to redirect and send a redirect (make sure to path authentication info in the request wrapper so that the logged in state is carried on)

Comment: So if i have a group called ABC , how would it be for only group ABC to redirect to particular landing page?

Comment: Yeah custom code is the only way, but can you give an example of that Ameesh?